# Batch Script - Create Dynamic Variable Names or Array in For Loop

Tags: arrays, variables, batch-file, dynamic, names

I would like to ask you if you can advise.

I don't know if it is possible to create dynamic variable names in batch or array or something like this. For example set c=0 before for loop and then set c = c+1 inside for loop and use this number to create dynamic variable name inside for loop e.g.: set entry%c% = 'somestring'

and afterwards use these numbered variables to print output outside for loop e.g.:
echo %entry1%
echo %entry2%

Example:

```
@echo off

set /a c=1

for %%i in (list.txt) do (

set /a c=c+1
set entry%c% = %%i

)

echo %entry1%
echo %entry2%
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look into delayed expansion variables. `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

Comment: See: [Arrays in cmd.exe (batch) script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: What's inside list.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" list.txt') do set "entry%%a=%%b"
```

but a word of warning about

```
set entry%c% = %%i
```

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. Had this worked, it would set a variable named "entry1<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>thefirstlineofthefile".

The `set "var=value"` syntax I've used ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

Comment: +1 This is quite clever. I like the use of find's /v switch to remove the possibility of empty variables, and of course /n to number the variables. A very good one liner.

Comment: Great! Thanks - exactly what I've been looking for. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delayed expansion variables, otherwise `c` will always expand to the same value.

You also need to remove the spaces in your set statement. `set entry%c% = %%i` will create a variable called (for example) `entry1<space>`, which you would have to expand like so - `%entry1 %`. So just remove those spaces around the `=` operator.

```
@echo off

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set c=0

for %%i in (list.txt) do (
    set /a c+=1
    set entry!c!=%%i
)

echo %entry1%
echo %entry2%
```

Also if you wanted to loop through all the variables you created, you could do something like the following.

```
for /L %%i in (!c!, -1, 1) do echo !entry%%i!
```

or

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, !c!) do echo !entry%%i!
```